# Assign value to a variable from several options where only one is defined

Tags: typescript

I'm not very well versed with typescript so I'm likely doing something silly, but I'm looking to assign a value to a variable inline from several options where only one is guaranteed to be defined. So, I'm looking to do something like:

```
// only one of these is defined at a time
//let defined: number[] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
let defined: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];

let undefA: any[] = undefined
let undefB: any[] = undefined
let undefC: any[] = undefined
let undefD: any[] = undefined

let value: unknown[] = defined || undefA || undefB || undefC || undefD
console.log(value)
```

`value` expects type `unknown[]` and I know that my input values are arrays, but they could be `number[]`, `string[]` or `boolean[]` and there's a limited amount of them and I do know all their names.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to group the right-hand side and tack on a `!`?

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to be a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/aNnp6W).  Right now I'm not sure exactly what's happening.  @CertainPerformance might have it right, but a good code example goes a long way to making things clear to people who want to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry @jcalz, I'm struggling to write up a reproducer that doesn't include a bunch of code from other parts of the system. The `!` is not quite I'm looking for, but I did notice trying to set the repro up that what I am trying to do is possible, I'm just limited by the context I'm trying to do it in, so I'll add a bit more detail to the original post, see if I can clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `type` keyword for customising desired type and assign this type to the variable.

```
type CustomiseType = number[] | string[] | boolean[]

const value: CustomiseType = yourVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well idiot me just realized the issue was elsewhere (another function I was using) and that this does actually work, you can use the `||` operator to exactly pick the one value that is defined out of a list of values.

Thanks everyone for the help!